# Why is the guard property for a toggle button ignored when it's name matches a property?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

When I have a ToggleButton defind like:

```
<ToggleButton Name="Taco"/>
```

And in my ViewModel:

```
public void Taco() {}

public bool CanTaco { get { return false; }}
```

The button is properly disabled.  But if I instead make Taco a bool property to reflect the ToggleButton's IsChecked state, it gets bound by CM's convention, but the CanTaco property is no longer used:

```
public bool Taco { get; set; }

public bool CanTaco { get { return false; } } // completely ignored
```

The button is enabled.  I can manually bind IsEnabled to CanTaco and it works properly again.

Is there a reason for the convention to not use the guard property in this case, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a limitation of the binding infrastructure than a bug.  Guard methods work against actions because we can "intercept" the method call and check the guard first. However when it's a property then the two way binding sets the property and there's nowhere to insert the checking of the guard.

Would be nice to have that functionality added but unfortunately not possible, guard methods will only work with methods and not properties.

Comment: Oh, I had thought that the guard properties got bound to IsEnabled by convention, since the controls get disabled when the guard returns false.  I guess I could try and add a custom convention that does it.

Comment: That may work, I'll add it as a possible feature for CM.